# get current element in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to use multiple select2 by using a class, like I am doing in autocomplete, but I am failing to do same in select2.

here is my code:

```
$('.select2-autocomplete').select2({
  placeholder: "Search",
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  multiple: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "http://example.com/autocomplete-results",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function(term, page) {
      return {
        q: term,
        type: $(this.element).data('type')
      };
    },
    results: function(data, page) {
      return {
        results: data
      };
    }
  },
});
```

Everything is working fine except this :

```
type : $(this.element).data('type')
```

Here I need the select2 element data-type value, but it is always undefined any idea how I can get that?

Thanks

Edit:

```
<input type="hidden" data-type="products" name="products" class="select2-autocomplete">
<input type="hidden" data-type="customers" name="customers" class="select2-autocomplete">
```

I want to show different results from ajax that is the reason I want to send data-type via ajax

Comment: is there any specific reason you need to set the datatype dynamically?

Comment: yes i have multiple select2 in my form, the server must be able to understand which result should be returned, so I want to pass a type parameter to server

Comment: A demo would be helpful.

Comment: you mean I have to give a fiddle example?

Comment: what do you mean by type? like "string" or "number"? or the type of input? textfield etc? does the element have a 'type' attr? this of any use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.type/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this.context)` and it will return the original select element as jQuery object.

```
data: function(term, page) {
  return {
    q: term,
    type: $(this.context).data('type')
  };
},
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. this.content is undefined

Comment: @nsimeonov `context`, not `content`

Comment: Sorry for the typo. All I have in `this` is 

`data: {.....}`
`dataType: "json"`
`processResults: ƒ (data, params)`
`transport: ƒ (a,b,d)`
`type: "GET"`
`url: "............"`

What worked for me is capturing the DOM element when `select2:open` is triggered

Answer (score 7):

You can do it capturing the active element during the select2:open event then use it into the data function

Here my example:

```
(function(){
var theSelect2Element = null;
$('.select2-autocomplete').select2({
   ...
   data: function(term, page) {
      return {
        q: term,
        type: $(theSelect2Element).data('type')
      };
   },
   ...
}).on('select2:open', function(e){ 
   theSelect2Element = e.currentTarget; 
}))();
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use $('.select2-container--open').prev('select.select2-autocomplete') and it will return the original select element as jQuery object.

```
data: function(term, page) {
  return {
    q: term,
    type: $('.select2-container--open').prev('select.select2-autocomplete').data('type')
  };
}
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.